# Create event before site loads

Tags: events

I want to create an event that triggers before the site loads to I grab the variables passed in the http header and send them to a plugin I have made.

I will have a url like http://www.foo.com?username=abc123

I want it immediately trigger a controller method located at: http://www.foo.com/actions/myPlugin/myMethod

Im just not sure how to connect the dots.

Comment: Would you want it to redirect to http://www.foo.com/actions/myPlugin/myMethod or just execute it, but keep the http://www.foo.com/?username=abc123 URL?

Comment: I need it to execute it, then I will be redirecting to the index page

Comment: Didn't the approach Brad posted work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head and in no way tested or thought through, you could put some logic in your plugin's `init()` method:

```
public function init()
{
    $username = craft()->request->getQuery('username');

    if ($username)
    {
        craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables(array(
            'username' => $username
        ));

        craft()->runController('myPluginHandle/myPluginActionMethod');
    }
}
```

Then in your plugins's controller:

```
class MyPluginController extends BaseController
{
    protected $allowAnonymous = true;

    public function actionDoIt($username)
    {
        // Do your thing.

        $this->redirect('homepage');
    }
}
```